# Assessing performance of entire nonlinear SUR in R?

Tags: r, computational-statistics, seemingly-unrelated-regressions

I understand the McElroy's R-squared is used to assess the entire SUR system in Hamann & Henningsen's `systemfit` package in R. However, I've been running SURs for systems of nonlinear equations using `nlsystemfit` and I'm having trouble assessing model strength between different SURs. When I look at the printed results, there isn't a McElroy's R-squared, and the $nlmest results are very scantly described on the web, and I've scoured high and low for clarifications on these items. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Q]: How do you assess SUR model performance between different nonlinear models with `nlsystemfit`?

Code:

```
equations <- list(equation1,equation2,equation3)
start.values <-c(b0=0.03877,..., b6=-0.8330)
labels <- list("Eq1","Eq2","Eq3")
SUR<-nlsystemfit(method ="SUR",equations,start.values,data=mydata,eqnlabels=labels)
print(SUR)
```

Last few lines of the Output:

```
$nlmest
$nlmest$minimum
[1] 109.9913

$nlmest$estimate
[1]  0.03746038  0.91701744  0.01030100  2.58307636  0.12774691  2.01356524 -0.84223465

$nlmest$gradient
[1] -1.028805e-04 -4.409446e-05  2.318937e-04  8.328134e-06  5.777720e-05  2.578367e-05
[7]  2.315360e-05

$nlmest$code
[1] 1

$nlmest$iterations
[1] 67


attr(,"class")
[1] "nlsystemfit.system"
```